# Google Chrome on macOS: Is there any way to move window buttons somewhere?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, menu-bar, tabs

Can I move close, exit full screen buttons to the left of the tab bar in the full screen mode on macOS? It`s really hard to use chrome cause everytime I hit the upper side to click on the tab, a line with these buttons appears together with the mac menu bar, and the whole page is moving down.

[image]

I tried disabling auto hiding the menu bar, but then this line just overlaps on the tab bar..

[image]

Maybe there is a way to move them to the active window itself or just remove at all?

Comment: This is utterly annoying as it is also leading to focus issues when switching to Chrome spaces, as the window manager buttons bar is what gets the focus, and not the tab strip that appears to be in focus.  And if you don't do a click to get focus, any keyboard shortcuts/commands you execute will effect whatever window that previously had focus.

Answer (score 1):

You've got to go to `chrome://flags`
Search for "Immersive Fullscreen Toolbar" and **enable** it.
Then restart your browser.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out what this setting actually achieved, because it gets complicated if you also have enabled the toolbar by default using the `View`>`Always show Toolbar in Full Screen` option. Good one :)